# Vertical middle align elements in 3-column layout

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment

Ok. I've tried for hours to get this, but no luck. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JE97D/3/.

Per this screenshot, I want to vertically align these elements in the middle without resorting to the use of margin-top.  Ideally the alignment could be made using line-height, but I haven't had luck trying to do so. This reason for this is that I can dynamically set where to align the elements when I'm using different container heights for my SASS mixin.

[image]

Comment: I am also open to an entirely different approach that doesn't use 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want it all in the middle.

If so, make the `line-height` the same as the `height` of the `div`.  Something like this:

```
#date-nav-container  {
    height: 100px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JE97D/4/

**EDIT**

As per the comment...

Do this and the *(This week)* reappears.

```
.smaller{
   margin-top:-40px;
   display:inline-block;
   float:left; 
   line-height:14px; 
}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JE97D/6/

However, this uses `margin-top`, which you said you didn't want to use.

Comment: Not quite. The text "This Week" has now disappeared.